# jQuery Autocomplete does not work on onKeyUp event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently developing a UI with jQuery autocomplete functionality. The autosuggestion is working fine but I cannot select the values using the keyboard. When I select a value using the keyboard, it get unselected immediately. Selecting with the mouse is fine. I've bound the following function to the onKeyUp event:

```
function setCreators(startDate, endDate) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtCreator").autocomplete(
      "getCampaignAuthors?stDate=" + startDate + "&enDate=" + endDate
    );
});
```

Why can't I select values using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
It's that onKeyUp event binding. I think jquery auto complete uses the same onkeyUp event for it's internal processing. So I changed the trigger event to onfocus. Now it's working fine.